# python3/hy - evaluating hy expressions in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval, hy

I know how to import an `hy` module into python. All I have to do is create a `something.hy` file containing `hy` code and then do the following ...

```
import hy
import something
something.func('args') # assumes there is an hy function called `func`
```

However, I haven't been able to figure out how to evaluate a string within python which contains `hy` code.  For example ...

```
hycode = '(print "it works!")'
hy.SOMEHOW_EVALUATE(hycode)
# I'd like this to cause the string `it works!` to print out.
```

Or this example ...

```
hycode = '(+ 39 3)'
result = hy.SOMEHOW_EVALUATE(hycode)
# I'd like result to now contain `42`
```

When using `hy` within python, is there any way to evaluate strings in this manner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `hy.read_str` and `hy.eval`.

```
>>> import hy
>>> hy.read_str("(+ 39 3)")
HyExpression([
  HySymbol('+'),
  HyInteger(39),
  HyInteger(3)])
>>> hy.eval(_)
42
>>> hycode = hy.read_str('(print "it works!")')
>>> hycode
HyExpression([
  HySymbol('print'),
  HyString('it works!')])
>>> hy.eval(hycode)
it works!
```

This works if you install Hy from Github master. If you need to make it work on an old version of Hy, you can see the implementation in the `hy` package's `__init__.py` is simply

```
from hy.core.language import read, read_str  # NOQA
from hy.importer import hy_eval as eval  # NOQA
```

Comment: It would seem that the API has changed once again, and nowadays the function is called `hy.read`. It can take both a string and a file-like object as input: https://docs.hylang.org/en/stable/interop.html#evaluating-strings-of-hy-code-from-python